# How to assign random class to *ngFor generated elements in the DOM?

Tags: angular, angular5

```
  <div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i = index;">
    <div class="project-card details-complete */random class/*">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have predefined classes = ['teal', 'pink', 'green', 'orange', 'magenta']; When *ngFor populates the DOM I wanna randomly assign one of those classes. I have tried to implement by generating random 0-4 number in the component and assign [class]="randomClassName():className" but I am getting expression changed after checked errors. [ngClass] did not help as well. Is there any way to implement this using directive or other api's?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[randomColor]'
})
export class RandomColorDirective implements OnInit {
   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: 
   Renderer2) {}
   ngOnInit(): void {
     const COLORS = ['teal', 'pink', 'green', 'orange', 
     'magenta'];
     let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
     COLORS.length);
     this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 
     `${COLORS[randomNumber]}`);
  }
}
```

Just in case someone needs it, I solved it using above directive.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose projects is your array so i you can map your colors with each of this project. I have one array of colors

```
colors = ['grad1', 'grad2', 'grad3', 'grad4', 'grad5', 'grad6'];
```

you can declare this color classes in your .scss file and map this colors in your .ts file as shown below

```
this.projects.map(project => {
          project.color = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
          return project;
        });
```

Also update in your .html file as shown below

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i = index;">
    <div class="project-card details-complete" [ngClass]="project.color">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In you .ts file -

```
public classValues = ['teal', 'pink', 'green', 'orange', 'magenta'];
```

In your HTML file -

```
 <div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i = index;">
    <div class="project-card details-complete classValues[i]" 
    [ngClass] = "(index == classValues.length - 1) ? index = 0:''">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Getting this error: Parser Error: Conditional expression (index == classValues.length - 1) ? index = 0:'' requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [(index == classValues.length - 1) ? index = 0:'']